# Spoj backpack DP explaination

Tags: matrix

I am trying to solve a problem on spoj.I created a dp solution but it gives me wrong answer.I am creating dp matrix and taking the maximum of previous answer and answer taking current good.

Can anybody explain a proper solution of the problem.
https://www.spoj.pl/problems/BACKPACK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just ACed this problem.

I don't know what exactly your "dp solution" is, but apparently this problem lies in the category of knapsack (still a DP problem). And according to the problem description, it's generally a [0/1 knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem). Therefore an equation like below is enough for the problem, where `opt[i]` denotes the maximum value that can be achieved for a backpack whose total volume is i.

```
opt[i] = max(opt[i], opt[i - items[j].vol] + items[j].value)
```

What makes this problem special is that each main item could have 0, 1, or 2 items attached to it. Say we have a main item `M`, and its two attachments `A1` and `A2`. Instead of considering `M, A1, A2` separately, we can imagine that there are 4 items bundled by them:

- `B1`, which is indeed `M` itself. Therefore `B1.volume = M.volume` and `B1.value = M.volume * M.c`.
- `B2`, is bundled by `M` and `A1`. `B1.volume = M.volume + A1.volume` and `B1.value = M.volume * M.c + A1.volume * A1.c`
- `B3`, is similar to `B2`, but replace `A1` with `A2`.
- `B4` consists of `M, A1,` and `A2`. `B4.volume = M.volume + A1.volume + A2.volume` and `B4.value = M.volume * M.c + A1.volume * A1.c + A2.volume * A2.c`

By doing the operations above, we can translate all items into bundles and we can perform 0/1 knapsack using these bundles.

Last but not least, note that for bundles generated by a same `M`, ONLY ONE of `B1, B2, B3,` and `B4` can be chosen. This may require a little bit of hacks, but shouldn't be complicated. :)